# Avro encoder/decoder on PHP - how to send encoded binary data without the schema itself?

Tags: php, apache-kafka, avro

**Preconditions**:

- Programming language: PHP.
- Serialization system: Apache avro
- PHP library: https://github.com/wikimedia/avro-php

I send various messages via Apache kafka, each message has its own structure (an array with a specific set of keys) and is sent to a strictly defined topic, the data itself is encoded and decoded using Apache avro.

**The problem** is that the schema itself is transmitted along with the data, which is redundant in my case (Highload), there is no point in this since the client (the consumer of messages from Kafka) owns the schemas for each message structure (one structure - one Kafka topic).

Apparently, the current package https://github.com/wikimedia/avro-php is not suitable.

**I'm looking for a ready-made solution - Avro encoder / decoder on PHP**, which will allow not sending the schema itself along with the data every time, but substituting it on the client side (it will be stored as a file and substituted depending on the topic). It will save disk space and network traffic.

**example of usage current solution:**

```
<?php

require_once('../lib/avro.php');

$schemaJson = <<<_JSON
{"name":"member",
 "type":"record",
 "fields":[{"name":"foo", "type":"int"},
           {"name":"bar", "type":"string"}]}
_JSON;

$item1               = ['foo' => 123, 'bar' => 'ktwop'];
$itemsForSerializing = [$item1];

$avroSchemaForWriter = \AvroSchema::parse($schemaJson);
$writeAvroStringIO   = new \AvroStringIO();
$avroIODatumWriter   = new \AvroIODatumWriter($avroSchemaForWriter);
$avroDataIOWriter    = new \AvroDataIOWriter($writeAvroStringIO, $avroIODatumWriter, $avroSchemaForWriter);

foreach ($itemsForSerializing as $itemForSerializing) {
    $avroDataIOWriter->append($itemForSerializing);
}

$avroDataIOWriter->close();

$encodedString = $writeAvroStringIO->string();
echo $encodedString . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// ACTUAL OUTPUT:
/* 
    Objavro.codenullavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"member","fields":[{"name":"foo","type":"int"},{"name":"bar","type":"string"}]} �k����N�*��1�V��ktwop�k����N�*��1�V�
*/

// EXPECTED OUTPUT: ktwop�k����N�*��1�V�

$readAvroStringIO = new \AvroStringIO($encodedString);
$avroDataIOReader = new \AvroDataIOReader(
    $readAvroStringIO, new \AvroIODatumReader($avroSchemaForWriter, $avroSchemaForWriter) // HERE I WANT TO USE SCHEMA FROM FILE ON CLIENT SIDE
);
echo "from binary string:" . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($avroDataIOReader->data() as $dataItem) {
    echo var_export($dataItem, true) . PHP_EOL;
}

//OUTPUT:
/*
    from binary string:
    array (
      'foo' => 123,
      'bar' => 'ktwop',
    )
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$io = new AvroStringIO();
$writer = new AvroIODatumWriter($schema);
$encoder = new AvroIOBinaryEncoder($io);
$writer->write($data, $encoder);
$io->string();
```